# test SignUp with auto incremented values for SignUp in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

How can i test SignUp with auto incremented values for SignUp id in Selenium Webdriver.
LIke i have right now hardcoded the signUp id and everytime i run the test i have to update the same. I want the test to run with auto incremented values each time without human intervention. HOw would it next time take id = testing02@abc.com and then testing03@abc.com and so on?

```
fd.findElement(By.id("SignUp_Id")).sendKeys("testing01@abc.com");
fd.findElement(By.id("SignUp_password")).sendKeys("test123");
    fd.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple for loop to

```
for(int count=1; count < 10; i++){
    fd.findElement(By.id("SignUp_Id")).sendKeys("testing" + i + "@abc.com");
    // Rest of the script
}
```

Comment: Created a util class with following function to generate random emails. 

  

public String generateEmail(int length)
   {
        String allowedChars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
                "1234567890" + 
                "_-."; 
        String email="";
        String temp=RandomStringUtils.random(length,allowedChars);
        email=temp.substring(0,temp.length()-9)+"@abcd.com";
        return email;
    }